# Locate the functionality of Wocommerce variation selection

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to find the functionality of the variation selection in a single product:
[image]

Does anyone know in what wocommerce php file this functionality is located? Or how can I search for it?

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for the actual render portion or the javascript functionality?

Comment: I'm looking for the javascript functionality thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JS file is located at `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/add-to-cart-variation.js`. That lists all the functionality that is encapsulated within the `VariationForm` class/object.

Answer (score 1):

Path : woocommerce/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php

Answer (score 1):

You can locate that selector in the file: woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php

Comment: Thanks mate, do you know where I could locate the js functionality of the dropdown? Thanks